# OracleConnection: what are Clearpool, Dispose and Close?

Tags: c#, oracle, exception

I would like to understand what does `Clearpool`, `Dispose`, `Close` do in OracleConnection?

After exception occurs, I would like to get rid off the current connection and create a total new connection with the same connection string. How should I get rid off the old connection?

Should l clearpool firstly or dispose the connection? And what does clearpool vs dispose/close do?

My current code is like below:

```
public virtual void Dispose()
  {
     try
      {
         _connection.Close();

      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
      }
      finally
      {
          _connection.Dispose();
          _connection.ClearPool();
          _connection = null;
      }            
  }
```

Comment: [Clearpool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/ConnectionClearPoolCtor1.htm) would be extreme - just because an exception occurs on one connection shouldn't mean the whole pool is corrupt. Also what kind of exceptions are you referring to? Dispose releases the connection back to the pool. Its a good thing to do once you've finished using it.

Comment: You really shouldn't have to do any of this - your OracleConnection probably shouldn't be stored as a field - it should be created in a using block. It will automatically close the connection and dispose of it when it falls out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am wondering why shouldn't "Clearpool"? I think "ClearPool" will empty the pool by discarding the specified connection and its associated connections. That means after we dispose the connection, we could use clearpool to get rid off all associated idle connections. Am I understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to create the connection inside a `using` block. Everything inside that block will be disposed whenever the block execution finishes. Also, do NOT leave a catch with no action inside. This might end on a silent exception that you will be not aware of.

```
using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("yourConnStr"))
{
    //ALL YOUR LOGIC INSIDE
}
```